# .NET Finalizer queue, stuck eating CPU

Tags: .net, performance

I have a managed app and long time after I perform an activity I persistently see (in process explorer) that fallowing stack eats up CPU:

```
ntoskrnl.exe!memset+0x64a
ntoskrnl.exe!KeWaitForMultipleObjects+0xd52
ntoskrnl.exe!KeWaitForMutexObject+0x19f
ntoskrnl.exe!__misaligned_access+0xba4
ntoskrnl.exe!__misaligned_access+0x1821
ntoskrnl.exe!__misaligned_access+0x1a97
clr.dll!@RtlDecodeUtf16LE@8+0x1a
clr.dll!_RtlCompareEncodedLBlobs@24+0xbc
clr.dll!_RtlCompareLUnicodeStrings@16+0x1b
clr.dll!?UpdateDerivedData@CInternalIdentityAttribute@@QAEJXZ+0x1fc
clr.dll!??$id_AssignInternalAttributeFromPublicAttribute@U_IDENTITY_ATTRIBUTE@Rtl@Isolation@Windows@@@@YGJPAU_RTL_ALLOCATION_LIST@@ABU_IDENTITY_ATTRIBUTE@Rtl@Isolation@Windows@@AAVCInternalIdentityAttribute@@@Z+0x94
clr.dll!??$id_ApplyDelta@U_IDENTITY_ATTRIBUTE@Rtl@Isolation@Windows@@P6IEPAU_RTL_ALLOCATION_LIST@@PAU_LUNICODE_STRING@@11PAX@Z@@YGJ_NPAU_RTL_ALLOCATION_LIST@@1PAU_INTERNAL_IDENTITY_TYPE@@KQAVCInternalIdentityAttribute@@PAKAAV?$CSmartArrayHolder@KVCInterna
clr.dll!??$id_InternalBaseIdentityValue_ApplyDeltas@U_IDENTITY_ATTRIBUTE@Rtl@Isolation@Windows@@P6IEPAU_RTL_ALLOCATION_LIST@@PAU_LUNICODE_STRING@@11PAX@Z@@YGJKPAU_RTL_ALLOCATION_LIST@@PAU_INTERNAL_IDENTITY_TYPE@@PAVCInternalIdentityValue@@KQBU_IDENTITY_AT
clr.dll!??$idapi_SetAttributeValue@U_IDENTITY_ATTRIBUTE@Rtl@Isolation@Windows@@P6IEPAU_RTL_ALLOCATION_LIST@@PAU_LUNICODE_STRING@@11PAX@Z@@YGJKU_BASE_IDENTITY@Rtl@Isolation@Windows@@PBU_IDENTITY_ATTRIBUTE@123@P6IEPAU_RTL_ALLOCATION_LIST@@PAU_LUNICODE_STRIN
clr.dll!@RtlSetBaseIdentityAttributeValue@24+0x16
clr.dll!@RtlSetReferenceIdentityAttributeValue@16+0x70
clr.dll!?IReferenceIdentity_SetAttribute@CReferenceIdentity@Com@IsolationImplementation@@IAEJPBG00@Z+0xa9
clr.dll!?SetAttribute@CReferenceIdentity_IReferenceIdentity@Com@IsolationImplementation@@MAGJPBG00@Z+0x17
clr.dll!?GetTextualIdentity@CAssemblyName@@QAGJPAGPAKK@Z+0x3ff
clr.dll!?GetDisplayName@CAssemblyName@@UAGJPAGPAKK@Z+0xa8
clr.dll!?GetAssemblyNameDisplayName@FusionBind@@SGXPAUIAssemblyName@@AAVSString@@K@Z+0x4a
clr.dll!?GetFileOrDisplayName@FusionBind@@QAEXKAAVSString@@@Z+0x6a
clr.dll!?RaiseAssemblyResolveEvent@AppDomain@@QAEPAVAssembly@@PAVAssemblySpec@@HH@Z+0x49
clr.dll!?ResolveAssemblyFile@AssemblySpec@@QAEPAVPEAssembly@@PAVAppDomain@@H@Z+0x26
clr.dll!?TryResolveAssembly@AppDomain@@QAEPAVPEAssembly@@PAVAssemblySpec@@H@Z+0x77
clr.dll!?PostBindResolveAssembly@AppDomain@@IAEHPAVAssemblySpec@@0JPAPAV2@@Z+0x8b
clr.dll!?BindAssemblySpec@AppDomain@@UAEPAVPEAssembly@@PAVAssemblySpec@@HHPAW4StackCrawlMark@@PAUAssemblyLoadSecurity@@@Z+0x425
clr.dll!?LoadDomainAssembly@AssemblySpec@@QAEPAVDomainAssembly@@W4FileLoadLevel@@PAUAssemblyLoadSecurity@@HHPAW4StackCrawlMark@@@Z+0x2bc
clr.dll!?LoadAssembly@AssemblySpec@@QAEPAVAssembly@@W4FileLoadLevel@@PAUAssemblyLoadSecurity@@HHPAW4StackCrawlMark@@@Z+0x19
clr.dll!?Load@AssemblyNative@@SIPAVObject@@PAVAssemblyNameBaseObject@@PAVStringObject@@_N22PAW4StackCrawlMark@@PAVAssemblyBaseObject@@PAV2@@Z+0x297
mscorlib.ni.dll+0x24e713
mscorlib.ni.dll+0x24e4ea
mscorlib.ni.dll+0x23d314
mscorlib.ni.dll+0x23cf95
mscorlib.ni.dll+0x23cd51
mscorlib.ni.dll+0x23caba
mscorlib.ni.dll+0x246619
System.ServiceModel.ni.dll+0x3113af
System.ServiceModel.ni.dll+0x30f3b7
System.ServiceModel.ni.dll+0x30f10e
System.ServiceModel.ni.dll+0x30ee1c
System.ServiceModel.ni.dll+0x30dccf
System.ServiceModel.ni.dll+0x2fb330
System.ServiceModel.ni.dll+0xbbc761
System.ServiceModel.ni.dll+0xbbc7d2
clr.dll!_CallDescrWorker@20+0x33
clr.dll!_CallDescrWorkerWithHandler@24+0x8e
clr.dll!?CallDescr@MethodDesc@@AAE_KPBEPAVMetaSig@@PB_KHH@Z+0x194
clr.dll!?CallTargetWorker@MethodDesc@@AAE_KPBEPAVMetaSig@@PB_KH@Z+0x21
clr.dll!?Call_RetArgSlot@MethodDescCallSite@@QAE_KPB_K@Z+0x1c
clr.dll!?ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanupHelper@@YGXPAUECWGC_GC@@@Z+0xbb
clr.dll!?ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup@ReflectionInvocation@@SIXPAVObject@@00@Z+0x138
mscorlib.ni.dll+0x234cba
mscorlib.ni.dll+0x272b66
mscorlib.ni.dll+0x2723f3
mscorlib.ni.dll+0x272299
clr.dll!_CallDescrWorker@20+0x33
clr.dll!_CallDescrWorkerWithHandler@24+0x8e
clr.dll!?CallDescr@MethodDesc@@AAE_KPBEPAVMetaSig@@PB_KHH@Z+0x194
clr.dll!?CallTargetWorker@MethodDesc@@AAE_KPBEPAVMetaSig@@PB_KH@Z+0x21
clr.dll!?QueueUserWorkItemManagedCallback@@YGXPAX@Z+0x4b
clr.dll!?**DoExtraWorkForFinalizer**@Thread@@QAEXXZ+0x114
clr.dll!?ShouldChangeAbortToUnload@Thread@@QAEHPAVFrame@@0@Z+0x101
clr.dll!?ShouldChangeAbortToUnload@Thread@@QAEHPAVFrame@@0@Z+0x399
clr.dll!?ShouldChangeAbortToUnload@Thread@@QAEHPAVFrame@@0@Z+0x43a
clr.dll!?ThreadPool@ManagedThreadBase@@SGXUADID@@P6GXPAX@Z1@Z+0x15
clr.dll!?DispatchWorkItem@ManagedPerAppDomainTPCount@@UAEXPA_N0@Z+0xe6
clr.dll!?NewWorkerThreadStart@ThreadpoolMgr@@CGKPAX@Z+0x20b
clr.dll!?WorkerThreadStart@ThreadpoolMgr@@CGKPAX@Z+0x3d1
clr.dll!?intermediateThreadProc@Thread@@CGKPAX@Z+0x4b
KERNEL32.dll!@BaseThreadInitThunk@12+0xe
ntdll.dll!___RtlUserThreadStart@8+0x70
ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart@8+0x1b
```

Any hints on what might cause this based on the call stack ?

Comment: Do you have any finalyzer(destructor) doing strange things, like locking, or making assumprions about the current thread?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken for "client" GC configuration there is one GC finalizer queue for all app (or something like that). I cannot tell where the problem might lie...

Comment: @Tibi is asking if you have any classes which have Finalize (`~ClassName()`) methods with suspect code.

Comment: Well it's quite a large app. If something on the call stack could lead us in some direction where to look at

Comment: Check in your code if you have any desctructors, and look in there for any smells!

Comment: @Tibi It didn't see the problem lately. It might have been because the application was creating to many threads at some point (because of a bug).